# WiFi funny business => "One" machine can ping "the other" but "the other" cannot ping "one." "The other" can browse "one" in explorer

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, ping

So I'm at work and I need my private server (my personal laptop) to communicate with my team's assigned machines.  I had Hamachi approved as a solution by all of our stakeholders only to have IT Security put the kabash on the idea.  They've got the servers blocked by default and would not grant us an exception.

So I set up a FoxFi mobile hotspot with my Droid (Samsung Galaxy SIII) and enabled shares on each of the machines.  On my network monitor, I can confirm that both devices are connected to the hotspot and have been assigned unique private IP addresses

192.168.43.110
192.168.43.33

### 110 is on a CORP domain|33 is on no domain.

So here's the funny business, and I'm hoping someone with understanding of these dynamics can provide a bit of insight into what could be causing this behavior and how to work around it.

110 can ping 33 fine.  110 can tracert 33 and gets a 1 hop response.  110 can access 33's Share in Windows Explorer via UNC.(challenged) 110 can access 33's Share in Windows Explorer via direct IP.(challenged)

33 cannot ping 110. 33 cannot tracert 110. 33 can access 110's Share in Windows Explorer via UNC. 33 can access 110's Share in Windows Explorer via direct IP (challenged)

Since 110 seems to have "better" access to 33 than 33 has to 110, I tried to open ssms under a runas command (with credentials on 33)

```
"Attempting to start ssm as user "MachineName\User" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - ssms
1311: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

(Does "runas" *require* a DC?)

What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe 110 has firewall rules in place that disallow ICMP packets?

Comment: I don't think that's the case (firewall blocking ICMP.)  3 months later and the behavior is still spotty.  Sometimes the machines behave well, sometimes they do not.  Sometimes refreshing the machines on the network correct the issue. Sometimes refreshing does not.  We haven't had any major topological changes that could explain it.  At this point, I'm just going to drop my concerns because they seem to be temporary. I was just curious if the description of the behavior stood out as anything specific to anyone that recognized it

Comment: What do you mean "refreshing the machines on the network"? What error messages do you get with the different comms mechanisms you're trying?

Comment: By "refresh" I meant dropping them from the network and adding them back.
The errors are "could not find" for the ping and "Unable to resolve target system" for the tracert and they are only one way